# How to remove index.php from Magento URLs?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, mod-rewrite

I followed all the steps in [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url) and the `index.php` has been removed from my **URL**, but when i click on a **product** or any **link** in my store it is a **redirect** me to root path.

**how i can fixes it ? any suggestion ?**

Comment: Did you re-index after changes?

Comment: The installation is in a subfolder?

Comment: yes i've re-index after changes

Comment: @RafaelCorrêaGomes , yes it is in subfolder.

Comment: Did you turn on "SEO" in your configuration?

Comment: @sIiiS how i can do this ?

Comment: go to your backend and `System->Configuration->Web->Search Engines Optimization` and in this tab set `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `Yes` ... don't forget re-index after this change!

Comment: Done , but does not any change appear. than you

Comment: after changing, empty cache and don't forget to re-index .... and if not changed, what is your web-server ? it used for Apache!

Comment: yes , it's Apache.